# android compiler query

Tags: android

In order to trace some variables in my code I have inserted a line to write the variable name and value to a file.    It seems that when I select 'Clean' to build the app sometimes a file which has had changes to the code is not recompiled unless I close and save it first.   This mystery has only just appeared and I am wondering if there is an option somewhere that has been accidentally changed. Does the compiler perhaps only recompile bits of the code in some fashion?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this, I've never faced it before.

However, a good common practice `Always save your files (Ctrl+S or Ctrl+Shift+S) before doing anything else)`